# How can I drag and drop a database column?

Tags: python, postgresql, drag-and-drop, plotly-dash

As part of a project, I want to visualize data, which is why I chose Dash. For example, the user should drag and drop the column Age and this will then be displayed graphically. How can I achieve this? 
I would prefer to display the individual columns as buttons, which he can then 'just' pull.

With dropdown menu it had worked and by drag and drop I could also read a CSV file.I have read the database table as a data frame. Thank you in advance!

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop  '

        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },

        multiple=True
    ),


    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(
        id='Graph2'
        ),
    ], style={'display': 'inline-block', 'width': '49%'}),
    ])
```

Comment: I'm not sure I properly understand your goal. Users will have a data table already, and they can use this app to display columns from that table? Instead of uploading the entire table, though, they only upload one column at a time? That sounds troublesome. Could you let users upload the entire data table at once, and then use another control to show the column they want?

Comment: I believe that I can not do it any other way, for the following reason: For example, we have a table of illnesses and the user wants to see if the diseases appear together with certain blood levels. Both would each be a column in another table, which is why I think you would have to choose that. Maybe I have a mistake, I'm sorry.

Comment: Will this data already exist in a database somewhere? If the user is not uploading the data, but rather access data already stored it may be easier for you to query the database yourself to obtain the available columns, and let the user then select from those options.

Comment: Yes, the data is already available, so can I just create buttons with the value df ['database column']?

Comment: Creating buttons would be a lot of trouble, because Dash needs the IDs to exist in the layout at load time. It might work more easily to use a multi-selection dropdown that contains the names of the columns.

Comment: With Dropdown I could choose individual columns, which has always worked well so far, I know that, but how can I use it to make a join? For example, if I really wanted to have column A from table A, but from table B column B?

Can I then work with radio buttons that have both and and as well as value and then write a query? I also thought about dropdowns, but that difficulty kept me going.

Just like : Select age, blood, id1, id2 from human join laboratory where human.id1= laboratory.id2
So a logical link between the elements. Thank you!

Comment: If you're doing a join with the tables, then it has to be on related columns anyway, so you don't need to make more than one selection. This is a fairly complex visualization from the sound of it, which might be more than a single SO question/answer can handle.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, I keep trying and if I can figure out the solution, I will post it here :)